# Is there any plugin hook that I can latch onto once a site is freshly installed?

Tags: installation

To customize a fresh new WP install, there are a bunch of pluginable functions that can be overridden. Namely `wp_install()` and `wp_install_defaults()`. And `wp_new_blog_notification()`.

I'd like to override a couple of default options without needing to keep custom versions of the latter in sync with core in my `wp-content/install.php` file.

I'm not finding any obvious hook to do so in the `wp-includes/upgrade.php` file, however. Might I be missing anything?

---

Edit: so, the `pre_option_$option_name` is valid for options. Is there another, or some not-too-twisted procedure, that would allow to auto-enable permalinks, including (important) writing to the htaccess file as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of interesting hooks for use in an `install.php`:

- `pre_update_option_{$option_name}`
  Generally useful to override defaults as they get stored.
- `added_user_meta`
  Allows to disable the welcome screen

But for heavy listing such as changing the default category's name, the default post and page, or changing permalinks, hooks are definitely missing. In particular, a bunch of options are added using `populate_options()`, and do so without any plugin hook whatsoever.

I've opened a ticket requesting new hooks here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25762

The easiest in the meanwhile is to override `wp_new_blog_notification()` — the function is relatively simple to keep in sync with the WP core.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a file at WP_CONTENT_DIR/install.php it will be run before the upgrade starts. If you want to override specific option then you can use the pre_update_option_$optionname filter to control the value written to the DB.

something like

```
add_filter('pre_update_option_admin_email','wpse_120475_myadminmail',10,2);

function wpse_120475_myadminmail($newemail,$oldemail) {
  return 'evil@me.com';
}
```

caution - wasn't tested but I assume that the filter API is available at that stage.

As for rewrite rules, the tricky part is generating the .htaccess file but since you obviously create your own installation image then you can add to it the .htaccess file in the root directory (the .htaccess is very generic and not tied to a specific domain name or directory location). Then all that is left to do is to control the rewrite rules options using the technique described above.

Comment: +1, since that would work for options. I'll edit my question, however, because I was hoping for one that might also allow to auto-enable permalinks.

Comment: updated the answer for that

Comment: I wish it were that simple. There are a few side effects that occur when the rules are flushed. :-) But it's a good lead indeed.

Comment: you right, I forgot that there is some writing to the DB, but guess it is only and AI call away, just don't ask me which :)

Comment: \*chuckle\*. But my question precisely *is*: which one? :-) Anyway, I'll keep looking…

Comment: ok,ok, will search the code :). you probably need flush_rewrite_rules, but you need to set them up first